# ionic2 with angular js 2 side menu icon not appearing after navCtrl push

Tags: android, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working in ionic2 , here i'm having a login page and on it will redirect to a side menu with swipe tabs page**[HomePage output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vjmu.png)  [home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MayD7.png)**.
I've used  **this.nav.push('HomePage')**to redirect from login page to home page. But I'm not getting the menu icon, it disappears and back icon is showing up.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you used `nav.push` instead of `nav.setRoot`. In Ionic, pushing a page adds it to a stack, and the back button `pops` it off the stack.

You want to use `setRoot` here:

```
this.nav.setRoot('HomePage');
```

Comment: I tried adding this.nav.setRoot('HomePage'); but the back icon is not showing. But menu (hamburger icon) gets disappeared.

Comment: I see you tried adding the new screenshots to my answer, you should edit your original post to include them

Comment: I think you should take a look at this doc, your html for the menu implementation is different http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#menus